# Get a mail notification whenever anyone connects a storage device

Tags: networking, server, usb, udev, mail-notification

I'm working in a Linux-based environment where there are more than 100 servers. I need to get a mail notification and popup notification whenever anyone connects a storage device. How do I configure that?

Comment: Is the popup notification local to the server or is this appearing on a remote machine like your personal desktop?

Comment: when i get both configuration steps . it becomes useful for me.

Comment: How quickly do you need to be notified?  Immediate? Within a minute? Once an hour?  Once a day?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to monitor for the word 'mount' in /var/log/syslog on a cronjob.  This sample would run every 10 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Gets the time and date 1 minute ago (00:00 would return 23:59 previous day)
TIME=`date +"%b %d %H:%M" --date '-1 min'`
# Truncate the minutes
TIME=${TIME::-1}

# Gets the past 10 minutes of logs and looks for 'mount'
MOUNT=`grep "$TIME" /var/log/syslog | grep mount`

if [ {{ '${#MOUNT}' }} -ge 1 ]; then
    echo -e "$MOUNT" | sendemail -t {{ email_address }} -f {{ from_address }} -u "$(hostname) Mount Detected" -s {{ smtp_server }} > /dev/null
fi
```

Make sure the date format matches what is in your logs.  You can use whatever sendmail command you wish.  If you wanted once a minute just remove the time truncate line.  If you wanted immediate, you'd need to monitor `udisksctl monitor` for output.  Once the email is sent, you can use any email notification for your popup.